# jquery put existing (reusable) functions in ajax request - cant use async:false

Tags: jquery, function

I have a few ajax functions* e.g.

```
 function MyFunctionA(PassingObj) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '123.ashx',data: PassingObj, type: 'POST',contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function (data1) {
                    return data1
                }
                }
            });

 function MyFunctionB(PassingObj) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '456.ashx',data: PassingObj,type: 'POST', contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function (data2) {
                    return data2
                }
                }
            }); 



var GetValuesXY(){
var x = MyFunctionA(PassingObj);            
var y = MyFunctionB(PassingObj);
return x + y;
```

}

MyFunctionA and MyFunction are general functions which are called all over the page and I dont want to implement callbacks if not possible, because they can be used in different situations.
I cannot set the Ajax functions to async:false - the option is deprecated from v1.8 and I am not allowed to use it, and it has caused problems (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

So to confirm, I can never successfully call the function GetValuesXY(){} as x will always be undefined as it will continue without waiting for a result as it is asynchronous.

Thus, 
Currently the only way i know how to handle the above is to merge the 2 and this is not acceptable in the situation:

```
function MyFunctionA(PassingObj) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '123.ashx',data: PassingObj,type: 'POST',contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function (data1) {

                     $.ajax({             //MyFunctionB is effectively copied in here
                        url: '456.ashx',data: PassingObj,type: 'POST',contentType: 'application/json',
                        success: function (data2) {
                            return data1 + data2
                        }
                        }
                    });
                }
                }
            });
```

Now I cant use the two example functions seperately at all, and it is very very inefficient way of programming  as I will possibly have an unlimited amount of permutations for this
and i will have to cut and paste for each of these every time i want to use any of the functions

Is it not possible to at least put the function calls in an ajax request? something to the tune of

```
var myData1;
var myData2;

                $.ajax({
                call MyFunctionA(),
                success: function (data1) {
                    myData1 = data1;
                        $.ajax({
                            call MyFunctionB(),
                            success: function (data2) {
                                myData2 = data2;
                                }
                            }
                        }); 
                    }

                }
            });
```

(*  - these are just dummy functions for demo purposes)

Comment: WHy don't you add a call back function to be run when you call `MyFunctionA` and make that the function to be run on success. Async AJAX is very different to Sync AJAX, for one Sync AJAX will actually halt the browser thread which is very different than what async does and is not reall recommended. Form what I see you want one function with an AJAX in to be callable from many locations and to be usable in many ways. As such as I would pass a callback function into the params of the `MyFunctionA`

Comment: Sometimes it is required to only call MyFunctionA without calling MyFunctionB, sometimes they need to be called together, sometimes MyFunctionC needs to be called as well. Obviously I cant go to Sync Ajax as mentioned, Im looking for help on a method to keep the functions separate and reusable. even if i could set up a callback function on an ad-hoc basis it would be fine e.g. var GetResults{ x : MyFunctionA(), y : MyFunctionB(), return GetResults.x() + GetResults.y()}

Comment: Hmm you could assign them to global objects and call their readystates: http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/ but this will apply to all AJAX requests made on the page not just the ones you are targeting. Without callbacks from the specific XMLHTTPRequest object it is kinda hard to get a specific endtime of a specific AJAX request in the way your trying.

Comment: You can also use that function to bind to a specific var holding the ajax() object but again you would need to reorder your code to what you've shown and tbh it would be easier to use a callback.

Comment: So it is possible with the idea of GetResults{ x : MyFunctionA(), y : MyFunctionB(), return GetResults.x() + GetResults.y()}?

Comment: I would say no, and even if it was the only way you could definitely say you are getting the specific AJAX requests back is to make them sync like when you load a browser page, and we know the problems with that. The way to do this is to use callbacks like `MyFunctionA(function(){ return data2; })` that might work, it might not though due to function scope (I always get confused by how deep callbacks can go).